# XSLT 2.0 sheet-uri not getting the correct data

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I am trying to pull data from an XML file that is defined in the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xpath-default-namespace="example.com">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="sheet-uri" select="'path/to/some.xml'"/>
    <xsl:param name="sheet-doc" select="document($sheet-uri)"/>

    <!-- Template here -->
    ...
    <xsl:for-each select="IsValid/time">
    <Debug>
        <xsl:variable name="referenced-code" select="$sheet-doc//Sheet/SomeData[time = current()]/id"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$referenced-code">
                <xsl:value-of select="$referenced-code"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>-1</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </Debug>
    ...
```

Source xml:

```
<Data xmlns="example.com">
    <id>21</id>
    <IsValid>
        <time>125622</time>
        <time>094522</time>
        <time>123456</time>
    </IsValid>
</Data>
```

The XML (`some.xml`) looks like this:

```
<Sheet>
    <SomeData>
        <time>125622</time>
        <id>1</id>
    <SomeData>
    <SomeData>
        <time>094522</time>
        <id>1</id>
    <SomeData>
    <SomeData>
        <time>123456</time>
        <id>0</id>
    <SomeData>
</Sheet>
```

This always ends up printing `-1` for `<Debug>`. Why is it not working correctly? This works fine when using XSLT 1.0. I'm trying to upgrade to 2.0 so I can use more functions.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one XML document has elements in a namespace but the other not then you obviously can't use `xpath-default-namespace` everywhere but need to use `<xsl:variable name="referenced-code" xpath-default-namespace="" select="$sheet-doc//Sheet/SomeData[time = current()]/id"/>`.

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

When you specify:

```
xpath-default-namespace="example.com"
```

this applies to **all** your XPath expressions. Since the `some.xml` file does not use this namespace, your variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="referenced-code" select="$sheet-doc//Sheet/SomeData[time = current()]/id"/>
```

ends up empty.

Comment: Thank you as well, I appreciate it!

Comment: P.S. You should look into using a [key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#key) to resolve cross-references.

Comment: Would it look something like this: `<xsl:key name="someId" match="SomeData" use="@id"/>`? Though, not sure how I would match the `<time>` to the `<id>`.

Comment: No, it would be `<xsl:key name="k" match="SomeData" use="time"/>`. And then you would do `<xsl:variable name="referenced-code" select="key('k', ., $sheet-doc)/id"/>`. That's roughly, not taking the namespace issue into account.

Comment: Ahh ok,that makes more sense. I can use Martin's solution on the namespace issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hmm, this ends up giving me the same problem as stated in the OP (even after adding the `xpath-default-namespace=""` to the variable). I'll keep researching on how to make it work, unless you might know why. I'm assuming it's because it's looking for `time/id` which doesn't exist.

Comment: This is not convenient. Post a new question, if you want to get into it in more depth.